# Make a grid system in React which changes the number of rows and columns?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have this content component which creates a bunch of Topic components, and each Topic is just a square which contains the topic name etc..

```
<div style={{ flex: 7 }}>
    {this.state.topics.length === 0 ? (
        <LoadingIcon />
    ) : (
        this.state.topics.map(topic => <Topic key={topic.id} topic={topic} />))}
</div>
```

I want to make it so that I have a grid system, so that my Topics are created one after another(left to right), and then when it reaches the end of the screen, I want to start in the next row, and it just put as much Topics as actually fit in a single row. I also want to make sure that when the window size is changed, that the rows and columns change again, so I don't have any overflow. How would I go about doing this? Thanks.

Topic component

```
import React from "react";

export default function Topic(props) {
    return (
        <div
            style={{
                display: "flex",
                flexDirection: "column",
                color: "black",
                backgroundColor: "white",
                width: "24em",
            }}
        >
            <div className="topic-name" style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>
                {props.topic.name}
            </div>
            <div className="topic-description">{props.topic.description}</div>
            <div className="topic-bottom-bar" style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
                <div>PostNumTemp</div>
                <div>AgeTemp</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your `Topic` component?

Comment: @larz sure, I added it to the original post.

Comment: looking for something like this https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-sea-0l3qu ?

Comment: Why flex: 7? This is as simple as setting the container css to display: flex. And that's it.

Comment: @BradEvans I have like a search bar above the flex: 7 div, and it has flex: 1, that's why.

Comment: @MoinulHossain flexWrap did exactly what I needed, thank you very much

Comment: @MoinulHossain I think  you can post your answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to tweak the styling a little.  Your top level div needs `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;` and your `<Topic />` doesn't need `display: flex;`.  Check out [my favorite flexbox resource](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) if you want to dive deeper.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
  <div class="child">6</div>
  <div class="child">7</div>
  <div class="child">8</div>
  <div class="child">9</div>
  <div class="child">10</div>
  <div class="child">11</div>
  <div class="child">12</div>
  <div class="child">13</div>
  <div class="child">14</div>
</div>
```